# Disable smooth fading when changing brightness of MacBook Pro Screen

Tags: display, screen

I'm on a late 2013 15" MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

Is there any way of disabling/enabling whether the display smoothly fades when the brightness keys are hit (F1 to lower, F1 to raise)? On my old computer, a late 2008 MacBook, it just snapped to the new brightness if I changed it in system preferences or used the Function Keys shortcut.

I want to do this because I am in a small theatre, and when I run light cues off my computer that black out the stage, I want it to snap to near-zero brightness, as opposed to the higher brightness I need to have it set to when the lights are up to prevent the screen from being washed out. I am setting the brightness via applescript.